# Can't boot Ubuntu anymore : paste from boot repair

Tags: boot, grub2, lenovo, bootloader, boot-repair

Lenovo t420 SSD

Not booting after bios reset to defaults. Can't seem to boot a ubuntu install disk from usb to try and correct the error. The drive is encrypted if that has any bearing. Have tried multiple solutions, not making much progress. Reaching out to the collective for help!

http://paste.ubuntu.com/24569421/

Comment: The partition-table looks really strange, the ESP (EFI System Partition) is missing relevant flags and your system partition (`sda3`) is so small, only 2 MB. We can't tell you what happened or what you have probably done yourself, it's just messed up. I don't think that it's fixable without a reinstall. To be able to boot your installer you probably have to disable `Secure Boot`  in UEFI-settings.

Comment: Yeah I dont know what happened. I am running a deeper search of the drive through partition magic live cd, still can't get usb boot. It's found more partitions, maybe it can repair them at the end. I am running 16.04, I want to make a live boot cd, but all the isos are for dvds, even the server version are too large >700mb. Thank you for responding though. I checked my bios and it doesn't contain a secure boot option, I also upgraded the bios. I did have a third party bios installed... But it was only to whitelist non-Lenovo wifi adapters. N